# How to get SinglePlatform location id from yelp search id?

Tags: api, yelp

I am using **yelp API** for getting **restaurant list** by its **search api**.
And now,I want to access data of **menu and photos** of that restaurant from singleplatform api,and for that i need **location id** of data of singleplatform api but i am not getting any id related to singleplatform api.

So,i want to know how to get singleplatform location id from yelp id which we get from search API.

And **matching api of singleplatform api** is currently in beta mode and sometimes it gives wrong data.so, i can not use that.

Help Appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Actually we had changed our approach then. And we didn't use singleplatform api then.